# Convergence of Integral of gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, analytic-functions

The reason for finiteness of the integral definition of the $\Gamma$-function in $\operatorname{Re}z>1$ is,

$$
\left|\int\limits_0^{\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t}\mathrm{d}t\right|\leq \int_0^{\infty}\left|t^{z-1}e^{-t}\right|\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^{\infty}t^{\alpha}e^{-t}dt,
$$ where $\alpha>0$. Now, for lower value of $t$ close to zero, $t^{\alpha}$ is small, and as $t$ increases, we can see by L' Hospital rule that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} t^{\alpha}/e^t=0$. Hence, intuitively the integral converges. But can anyone give a more formal explanation of this?

Comment: What is your question? Are you trying to understand why the integral converges for $\operatorname{Re}z>1$?

Comment: Yes, I gave a intuitive explanation for this, but I formal explanation would be helpful

Comment: I would appreciate an upvote and a tick :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting the integrals up
$$\int\limits_0^\infty t^{\alpha-1}e^{-t}dt=\int\limits_0^1 t^{\alpha-1}e^{-t}dt+\int\limits_1^\infty t^{\alpha-1}e^{-t}dt$$

Now, we have that

$$0\le t\le 1\;\implies\;\; t^{\alpha-1}e^{-t}\le t^{\alpha-1}\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\;\int\limits_0^1t^{\alpha-1}dt=\left.\frac{t^\alpha}\alpha\right|_0^1=\frac1\alpha$$

and we also have that for sufficiently big $N$, with $N\leq t$

$$t^{\alpha-1}e^{-t}\stackrel{\text{}}\le e^{-t/2}\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\;\int\limits_1^\infty e^{-t/2}dt=\left.-2e^{-t/2}\right|_1^\infty=2 e^{-1/2}.$$

Comment: For your second inequality, there has to be some condition on $\alpha$. It is not true for all $\alpha>0$ (otherwise $\Gamma(\alpha)$ would be bounded when $\alpha$ is bounded away from zero).

Comment: It is $\alpha>1$ in the second inequality

Comment: So $\Gamma (\alpha ) \le \frac{1}{\alpha } + 2e^{ - 1/2}$? In particular $\Gamma(\alpha)<3$ for $\alpha\geq 1$?

Comment: You can use for example $$
e^{t/2}  = 1 + t +  \cdots  + \frac{{t^{\left\lceil {\alpha  - 1} \right\rceil } }}{{2^{\left\lceil {\alpha  - 1} \right\rceil } \left\lceil {(\alpha  - 1)!} \right\rceil }} +  \cdots  > \frac{{t^{\alpha  - 1} }}{{2^{\left\lceil {\alpha  - 1} \right\rceil } \left\lceil {(\alpha  - 1)!} \right\rceil }},
$$ i.e., $$
2^{\left\lceil {\alpha  - 1} \right\rceil } \left\lceil {(\alpha  - 1)!} \right\rceil e^{ - t/2}  > t^{\alpha  - 1} e^{ - t}
$$ for all $t\geq 1$.

Comment: You may remove $1\leq t$ and integrate form $N$.

Comment: @vitamind can you explain your second inequality, does it follows from the example you gave?

Comment: @Gary how did you get $t^{\alpha -1}e^{-t}<e^{-\frac{t}{2}}2^{\alpha -1}(\alpha-1)$, shouldn't that be $t^{\alpha -1}<e^{-\frac{t}{2}}2^{\alpha -1}(\alpha-1)$, i.e. without the $e^{-t}$  factor?

Comment: @AlexanderCska You multiply through my inequality with $2^{\left\lceil {\alpha  - 1} \right\rceil } \left\lceil {\alpha  - 1} \right\rceil !e^{ - t}$. Note that I put the $!$ at an incorrect place in my original comment.

Comment: @Gary Is the roof bracket there to deal with non-integer $\alpha$ too?

Comment: @AlexanderCska Yes, that is right.